# about Android LazyAdapter....Loading Image in ListView

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading

I used Lazy Loader to load image in my listView

and the image is from site

I parse the image's url to a String array

and set LazyAdapter like this

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, aStrArray);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm sure about the aStrArray is not the problem.

(I had Logged it before)

But the ListView just Load the first one Image...

why is that?

Here's my code

```
public class BBtest08Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
String aStr;
String aStrArray[];
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    try {
        executeHttpGet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("bird","parser failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
public void executeHttpGet() throws Exception {
    try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/GetMovies.js");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); 
     String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),"utf-8");
     retSrc = retSrc.substring(1);//there a space in the very first
       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(retSrc);
       JSONArray movieArray = obj.getJSONArray("movies");
       for(int i = 0;i < movieArray.length(); i++)
       {
       JSONObject movie_data = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
       aStr = aStr+movie_data.getString("imageUrl")+",";
       aStrArray = aStr.split(",");
       }
       } finally {
           adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, aStrArray);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
       }
}
```

The Lazy Loader from author is like this---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

private String[] mStrings={
        "http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fmen7122923814_s.jpg",
        "http://test.mobibon.com.tw/MovieGoTest/Pics/pl_fmen7122923814_s.jpg",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/768060227/ap4u_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/74724754/android_logo.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/681537837/SmallAvatarx150_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/63737974/2008-11-06_1637_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/548410609/icon_8_73_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/612232882/nexusoneavatar_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/213722080/Bugdroid-phone_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/645523828/OT_icon_090918_android.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827025/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/850960042/elandroidelibre-logo_300x300_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/655119538/andbook_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/121630227/Droid_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/957149154/twitterhalf.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/97470808/icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/511790713/AG_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/956404323/androinica-avatar_normal.png",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/909231146/Android_Biz_Man_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/72774055/AndroidHomme-LOGO_normal.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/349012784/android_logo_small.jpg",
        "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/841338368/ea-twitter-icon_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/64827024/android-wallpaper6_2560x160_normal.png",
        "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/77641093/AndroidPlanet_normal.png"
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is more important is the getView function inside the LazyAdapter, you should log inside the getView function to see what url is actually set by the imageView.

Also, why are you splitting aStr every loop? You should just append new URL to aStr inside the loop and split it into array after the for loop.

Comment: BTW, if you want Chinese answer you can contact me personally via email

Comment: are you a Taiwanese..?

I want to call you...

BTW...getView function inside the LazyAdapter get every url...

but just show the very first image....

Comment: No I am from HK. Can you post the code of getView? I persume it is reading wrong position from the array.

Comment: I've found out a question....
that is if I type my image url directly to the array in sample code from author....It still 「not display it...」....

is the image's has problem?

but i can see them normally in my browser

BTW...the only one which can display out is the very first image

and it works if i type the first image url directly to the array in sample code!

so....I doubt that the problem is from the image itself...

Comment: it can be the cause, I try it with my copy of lazy list now

Comment: I randomly try 4 URLs in the json file and it works perfectly

Comment: I copied your code to the lazy list (adding a minor change by setting aStr to "" but not leave it null at the beginning), it runs on my device smoothly. You should check your connection

Comment: I....I know why...already...

『I forget to set permission to android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE』。。。

sorry for my stupid.....and thanks for your help^^